# Excel value range

Tags: excel

i have the following issue:

- In column G i have a point value in the cell.
- In cell U i have a value that is currently static but I want it to be changing according to the value of G.

  - If G is between 1-10 then U should be 2,
  - if G is between 11-22 then U should be 3 and
  - if G is between 23 and 34 then U should be 4.

I have tried many different formulas and it seems to all break on the fact that i can't use the formula result to calculate another formula in a different cell.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Joe

Comment: "i can't use the formula result to calculate another formula in a different cell" Why not? As written, this question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=IF(A3<11,2,IF(AND(A3>10,A3<23),3,IF(AND(A3>22,A3<35),4,"oooops")))
```

It uses a series of nested IF methods as well as an AND:

- If the number satisfies your first condition return 2
- Else, if the number satisfies your second condition (which is 2 checks hence the use of AND), then return 3
- Else, if... you get the point

[image]

Comment: Thank you David i have used this formula and it worked just fine. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATCH`, it will scale easily with any number of ranges you have.

```
=1+MATCH(G1,{1,11,23,35})
```

You can also use nested IF's as in the answer of @DavidBrossard, but it could be further simplified without using AND's.

As commented by @JohnColeman, I don't see anything that prevents nesting this formula inside something else.

Comment: @DavidBrossard yep, and it is the equivalent of your nested IF's, but notice that you can remove the `AND`'s because with each new test, the previous one has already failed. (That's what made me post another answer btw after some hesitation) :)

Comment: makes sense! I should have thought of that